# attributes extraction and comparision in perl twig

Tags: xml, perl

I have a large XML file

```
        </ADDRESS>
    </EXTRACT>
</LIST>
<LIST NAME="QWER" PORT_ALIAS="2" ROLL="640"   DIRECTION="I">
    <EXTRACT>
        <ADDRESS>
            <HOME ROLLNO="36896" SECTION="A"/>
            <HOME ROLLNO="36896" SECTION="B"/>
        </ADDRESS>
    </EXTRACT>
</LIST>
<LIST NAME="QWER" PORT_ALIAS="3" ROLL="2200"  DIRECTION="O">
    <HIGHT NB="1" FEE_SUBMIT="FALSE">
        <TICKET>
            <CLASS SECTION="A" ROLLNO="29582"/>
            <CLASS SECTION="B" ROLLNO="29582"/>
        </TICKET>
    </HIGHT>
</LIST>
<LIST NAME="QWER" PORT_ALIAS="4" ROLL="640"
    DIRECTION="I">
    <EXTRACT>
        <ADDRESS>
            <HOME ROLLNO="37556" SECTION="A"/>
            <HOME ROLLNO="37556" SECTION="B"/>
        </ADDRESS>
    </EXTRACT>
</LIST>
```

I am using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) to extract values from the XML data.

If the first child of `LIST` is `HIGHT` then I have to extract the value of `DIRECTION`, `ROLL`, `ROLLNO` and `NB`. Also I want to put them separately according to `DIRECTION` - `O` or `I`.

If DIRECTION is `O` then all values will be printed separately as in case the first child is `HIGHT`

```
OUPUT===> ROLL, ROLLNO, NB
INPUT ==> ROLL, ROLLNO, NB.
```

```
use XML::Twig;
my $filename = 'report.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename);

my $phraser = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => { LIST => \&process_list, });
$phraser->parsefile("doc.xml");

sub process_list {
  my ($twig, $list) = @_;
  my $conformation = $list->att('DIRECTION');
  my $fee          = $list->att('ROLL');

  if (defined $list->first_child('HIGHT')) {
    foreach my $primary (
      $list->first_child('HIGHT')->first_child('TICKET')->children()) {
      my $val      = $primary->att('NB');
      my $group_id = $primary->att('ROLLNO');

      if ($conformation eq 'O') {
        print $fh "\n output ===> $conformation, $fee, $group_id , $val \n";
      }
      if ($conformation eq 'I') {
        print $fh "\n INPUT Queuing ===> $conformation, $fee, $group_id ,$val \n";
      }
    }
  }
}

close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

I am getting output like this

```
output ===> O, 2200, 29582 ,  

output ===> O, 2200, 29582 ,  

INPUT Queuing ===> I, 500, 29619 , 

INPUT Queuing ===> I, 500, 29619 , 

INPUT Queuing ===> I, 500, 29620 , 

INPUT Queuing ===> I, 500, 29620 , 

output ===> O, 132, 29580 ,  

output ===> O, 132, 29580 ,
```

the output is mixed.

Also I am unable to extract the value of `NB`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract the `NB` attribute from the children of the `TICKET` elements when it is an attribute of `HIGHT`.

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* program, especially hen you are asking for help with it. It is the very least you can do to check that your program is correct.

You must *always* test the success of every `open` call, by writing something like.

```
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die $!;
```

Alternatively you can enable the `autodie` pragma which does this for you.

I encourage you to look at the [`XML::Path`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Path) module, which makes accessing XML data much more simple.

This program shoukd do what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use XML::Twig;

my $filename = 'report.txt';
open my $fh, '>', $filename;

my $parser = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => { LIST => \&process_list, });
$parser->parsefile('doc.xml');

sub process_list {
  my ($twig, $list) = @_;

  my $direction = $list->att('DIRECTION');
  my $roll      = $list->att('ROLL');

  my $hight     = $list->first_child('HIGHT')   or return;
  my $ticket    = $hight->first_child('TICKET') or return;
  my $nb        = $hight->att('NB');

  for my $primary ($ticket->children) {

    my $rollno = $primary->att('ROLLNO');

    printf $fh "\n%s ===> %d, %d, %d\n",
        $direction eq 'O' ? 'output' : 'INPUT Queuing',
        $roll,
        $rollno,
        $nb;
  }
}

close $fh;
print "done\n";
```